# Invalid selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

I am creating a applications for teachers that will store Courses and students as well as keep track of grades. Right now it is set up in a data model that stores the courses in an array. The courses are objects that include an array of students and assignments. I have a tableview of all the courses that transitions to a tableview of students. In the courses detail view I have a tableview cell that transitions to a third table view for the assignments. My problem is occurring here. When I try to add an assignment to the tableview I am getting the error:  'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b38620'..

Here is some code that I believe may contain the problem.

Course detail view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AssignmentTable"]) {

    AssignmentViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.checklist = checklistToEdit;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 2)
    {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"AssignmentTable" sender:checklistToEdit];


    }
}
```

Assignment View controller:

```
- (void)editAssignmentViewController:(EditAssignmentViewController *)controller     didFinishAddingItem:(Assignment *)item
{
int newRowIndex = [self.checklist.assignments count];

[self.checklist.assignments addObject:item];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];


[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Assignment Detail View Controller:

```
- (IBAction)done
{
if (assnToEdit == nil) {
    Assignment *item = [[Assignment alloc] init];
    item.texta = self.textFielda.text;

    [self.delegate editAssignmentViewController:self didFinishAddingItem:item];


} else {
    self.assnToEdit.texta = self.textFielda.text;

    [self.delegate editAssignmentViewControllerDidCancel:self]; 
}

}
```

Comment: How do you declare and create the assignments object that you use in `[self.checklist.assignments addObject:item];` ?

Comment: The "Assignment" object is declared and constructed as a class that contains two strings and an ID. The array of assignments is declared as a NSMutable array as a part of the Course object.

Comment: What does the code look like where you initialize your assignments array?  I also suggest debugging your code by stepping through it to verify which actual line causes the error.  I *assume* it's the one I quoted above because that's the only place you show 'addObject' but it would be nice to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

The object you've stored in the `assignments` property is an instance of `NSArray`, which is immutable. You need that to be an instance of `NSMutableArray` instead. That's the reason `addObject:` is an unrecognized selector -- it's a method that exists in `NSMutableArray` but not in `NSArray` and your code is sending it to an instance of `NSArray`.

Comment: See, but I have declared that 'assignments' is an NSMutable array. I feel like maybe I am not understanding what you are trying to tell me. The object I am trying to store in assignments is simply an object. Why would an array I have declared and initialize as an NSMutable array not accept it.

Comment: @user1170015 `assignments` is a property that *contains* an array. At some point in your program you had to store an array in the `assignments` property, or else its value would be nil. The object you used to set the property's value was an instance of `NSArray`. In all likelihood you're ignoring a compiler warning that would otherwise have alerted you to that issues.